# Visa to Georgia on Pakistani Passport from Embassy of Georgia in Malaysia

Tags: visas, malaysia, georgia-country

I am a Pakistani passport holder residing in KL, Malaysia. Is this possible for me to get a visa to Georgia from the Georgian embassy in Malaysia?

Comment: Aside from possibly having to prove you have the right to live in Malaysia, you should be ok to apply for a visa.

Comment: Without speaking to Georgia, every country I've looked up (China, Russia, Belarus, etc.) allowed holders of long-term residence permits to apply from the country in which they are living, as opposed to their country of citizenship. In this case, however, Georgia appears to offer you an [electronic visa application](https://www.evisa.gov.ge/GeoVisa/en/VisaApp) by Internet without going to any consulate.

Comment: Sounds like an answer @AndrewLazarus

Answer (score 2):

Without speaking to Georgia, every country I've looked up (China, Russia, Belarus, etc.) allowed holders of long-term residence permits to apply from the country in which they are living, as opposed to their country of citizenship. In this case, however, Georgia appears to offer you an [electronic visa application](https://www.evisa.gov.ge/GeoVisa/) by Internet without going to *any* consulate.